# Should I wrap blocking code with Future within an actor?

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka, actor

I have a question regarding of  blocking call handling within an actor. I have a blocking method call `blokingProcess()` I want to call it within an actor. Should I have to

1. Wrap this  `blokingProcess()` by `Future` with a dedicated `dispatcher/ExecutionContext` in an actor then using `pipeTo self`. **Or**
2. I should create a `supervisor parent actor` under which I will produce `child actor` with dedicated `dispatcher` . That child actor  will handle the blocking call  `blokingProcess()` without any `Future` wrapper .

Note I can also call `blokingProcess()` by wrapping with `Future` with `dedicated dispatcher/ExecutionContext` with in no actor. My programme will generate so many blocking calls at a time . I don't need response back.

I know this is very silly question. But looking for experts' suggestions.

Comment: It's not a silly question :D. I would go with the second approach, creating a supervisor actor. If you mean something like fire and forget when you say "I don't need the response", the child actors will take care of processing the message, and might send some small reports about the states of the jobs. Actors are entities that are "async in nature", so doing something like `Future{...}` inside an actor context is not something very common, passing the message to another actor which can process it inside itself, is more meaningful.

Comment: @AminMal Many APIs return a `Future` for asynchronous operation so it is actually quite common to use `Future` inside an Actor and use `pipeTo` to send the output to an actor.

Comment: @Tim yes ofc, but the problem here is slightly different, it’s kind of like master-slave jobs, the return value is not needed, so that’s why.

Comment: @AminMal The problem is no different from other situations where `Future` is a perfectly good solution (sending an HTTP response, for example).

Comment: @Tim, I see, I didn't mean that Future here is a bad solution or whatever, but when the task is time consuming, I would prefer the master-slave approach rather than the `Future`, you mentioned sending an HTTP response, which is a little bit time consuming, but what about some situations like training some factorization model? This is also time-consuming, `Future` would work here indeed, but the child actor approach would be a better fit, makes more sense (for me though).

Answer (score 1):

You generally don't want to perform long-running thread-blocking work on threads of your `ActorSystem`'s main dispatcher pool. This is because it is that same pool that handles **all** the events in your application (unless specifically directed to another pool) -- so if that pool gets saturated with blocked threads, your application will deadlock.

The pattern I recommend is to set up a [separate dispatcher](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/dispatchers.html) for IO-bound blocking work. Then you can use in one of two ways, either in a single actor:

```scala
implicit val ioDispatcher: ExecutionContext = context.system.dispatchers
  .lookup(DispatcherSelector.fromConfig("io-bound-dispatcher"))

val task = Future {
  blocking {
    // blocking work here
  }
}
```

or in a parent-child fashion, where the IO-bound dispatcher is used for all work done by the child:

```scala
// in parent
val child = context.spawn(
  childBehavior,
  "child-actor-name",
  DispatcherSelector.fromConfig("io-bound-dispatcher")
)
child ! msg
```

and have the child run the blocking action on its main thread, which will be a thread from the IO-bound dispatcher's pool.

The advantage to the second approach is it makes recovery/supervision work like it does for any other actor; in other words, if your blocking operation throws an uncaught exception, it will bubble up the supervision stack until handled. This may or may not be what you want.

In either case, it's always good to add some logging around the blocking code which will allow you to inspect the thread name that the action is occurring on. (Warning! Akka's default logging logs all events on the **default** thread pool; you have to explicitly request that the log event's `sourceThread` from MDC is added to the log output.)

Note that all of Akka's own IO primitives (e.g. HTTP client, Kafka consumer, etc.) are designed (usually by means of the Streams APIs) to not block dispatcher threads. So you should not move these to other dispatchers unless you are very, **very** sure that it is they that are causing thread-pool starvation (and not merely being the victim of it).

Answer (score 1):

My answer is

3. Wrap in a `Future` and use `blocking`

If you put `blockingProcess` inside a `blocking` block then the dispatcher can use a dedicated thread for that `Future` and avoid the risk of deadlock.

```
Future{
  blocking{
    blockingProcess()
  }
}
```

Using separate dispatchers or child actors feels like overkill to me.

This does depend on the particular dispatcher being used, so see [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#blocking) for more details.